# How to access Youtube Data API v3 with R

Tags: r, youtube-data-api

I am trying to use R to retrieve data from the YouTube API v3 and there are few/no tutorials out there that show the basic process. I have figured out this much so far:

```
# Youtube API query
base_url <- "https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/"

my_yt_search <- function(search_term, max_results = 20) {
  my_api_url <- str_c(base_url, "search?part=snippet&", "maxResults=", max_results, "&", "q=", search_term, "&key=", 
                      my_api_key, sep = "")
  result <- GET(my_api_url)
  return(result)
}

my_yt_search(search_term = "salmon")
```

But I am just getting some general meta-data and not the search results. Help?

PS. I know there is a package 'tuber' out there but I found it very unstable and I just need to perform simple searches so I prefer to code the requests myself.

Comment: you're using `part=videoDuration` which is not a valid part

Comment: Right, forgot to change that back, was trying it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there is no way to directly get the durations, you'll need to call the `videos` endpoint (with the part set to `part=contentDetails`) after doing the search if you want to get those infos, however you can pass as much as 50 ids in a single call thus we can save some time by pasting all the ids together.

```r
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

my_yt_duration <- function(...){
  my_api_url <- paste0(base_url, "videos?part=contentDetails", paste0("&id=", ..., collapse=""), "&key=", 
                     my_api_key )
  GET(my_api_url) -> resp
  fromJSON(content(resp, "text"))$items %>% as_tibble %>% select(id, contentDetails) -> tb
  tb$contentDetails$duration %>% tibble(id=tb$id, duration=.)
}

### getting the video IDs

my_yt_search(search_term = "salmon")->res
## Converting from JSON then selecting all the video ids
# fromJSON(content(res,as="text") )$items$id$videoId 
my_yt_duration(fromJSON(content(res,as="text") )$items$id$videoId) -> tib.id.duration
```

```
# A tibble: 20 x 2
   id          duration
   <chr>       <chr>   
 1 -x2E7T3-r7k PT4M14S 
 2 b0ahREpQqsM PT3M35S 
 3 ROz8898B3dU PT14M17S
 4 jD9VJ92xyzA PT5M42S 
 5 ACfeJuZuyxY PT3M1S  
 6 bSOd8r4wjec PT6M29S 
 7 522BBAsijU0 PT10M51S
 8 1P55j9ub4es PT14M59S
 9 da8JtU1YAyc PT3M4S  
10 4MpYuaJsvRw PT8M27S 
11 _NbbtnXkL-k PT2M53S 
12 3q1JN_3s3gw PT6M17S 
13 7A-4-S_k_rk PT9M37S 
14 txKUTx5fNbg PT10M2S 
15 TSSPDwAQLXs PT3M11S 
16 NOHEZSVzpT8 PT7M51S 
17 4rTMdQzsm6U PT17M24S
18 V9eeg8d9XEg PT10M35S
19 K4TWAvZPURg PT3M3S  
20 rR9wq5uN_q8 PT4M53S
```

Comment: Wow, this actually works but I don't know how you got the IDs when I do not see them in the list that my_yt_search functions retrieves. I am assuming they are somehow encoded in the json response the api call makes and not readable through Rstudio?

Comment: Also, do you know how the API call orders the videos? Because the results don't match my own YouTube search or even an incognito search. The videos are there but the ranking is off.

Comment: @GreenManXY that's y I use `content(res,as="text")` to get the response as plain text then parse the json with `fromJSON(content(res,as="text") ) -> res` then if you call `str(res)` it'll be clear where the ids are i.e `res$items$id$videoId`, for the order of the videos sadly I have no info about y it would differ.